# Не могу получить столбцы таблицы при парсинге сайта

Tags: c#, html, htmlagilitypack

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Parser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = Parsing(url: "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B");
        }

        private static object Parsing(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                using(HttpClientHandler hdl = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = false, AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.None})
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient(hdl))
                    {
                        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
                        {
                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var html = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
                                {
                                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                                    doc.LoadHtml(html);
                                    var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='mw-body']//div[@class='vector-body']//div[@class='mw-body-content mw-content-ltr']//div[@class ='mw-parser-output']//table[@class='wikitable']//tbody");
                                    if (table != null)
                                    {
                                        var rows = table.SelectNodes(".//tr");
                                        if (rows != null)
                                        {
                                            foreach(var row in rows)
                                            {
                                                var cells = row.SelectNodes(".//td");
                                                if (cells != null && cells.Count > 0)
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine(cells.Select(c => c.InnerText));
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Как бы я не пытался, в cells всегда получаю null. Почему так происходит и как исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для начала, вы делаете оооооооочень много лишних и порой неправильных телодвижений. 1. `HttpClient` должен быть создан **только раз** и служить **все время жизни приложения**! 2. `.GetAsync(url).Result` - это очень плохо, сделайте нормальный `Task` и используйте правильно `async/await`. 3. `new HttpClientHandler()` - все его параметры по сути лишние, зачем они там? 4. `.//div[@class='mw-body']//div[@class='ve...`  - зачем вы прописываете **весь** XPath до объекта? Достаточно последнего, с укананием Id и/или Class (то есть `table[@class='wikitable']//tbody`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, появилась ещё проблема, если я прописываю полное название класса у тега table, то и table тоже равен null :(. Не разбираюсь вообще в этой теме, код был взят из старого пример. Может ли это быть связано с тем, что данные на сайт загружаются с помощью скриптов?

Comment: Отвечая на вопрос "почему Null?" Посмотрите внимательно на этот кусок `//table[@class='wikitable']`, тут вы говорите "дай мне `table`, класс которого равен `wikitable`", а теперь смотрим на то, что в HTML `class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"` - будет ли `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter` == `wikitable`? Нет, но оно содержит это значение, так может `table[contains(@class, 'wikitable')]`? Вообще, весь ваш Xpath можно переписать на такое `.SelectNodes(".//table[contains(@class, 'wikitable')][1]//tr")`, все, результатом получите все строки из первой таблицы.

Comment: Чем вам `var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);` не угодил, зачем вот это вот всё? ) хандлер тоже можно полностью выкинуть из кода.